# show pdf file inside android app from server url without give the permission download that file

Tags: java, android-studio, pdf, android-intent

show PDF file inside the android app from the server URL without give permission to download that file. how it can do in the android app.
I have tried using web_view but it allows us to download it.
I won't open that file in the activity. but only display that file not allow to download it.

Answer (score 0):

> Hope this helps you, it will only allow users to view the PDF not download it. You can add this inside your webview and pass the PDF inside it. Drop in comments if you need more assistance

```css
body {
    margin: 0;
    font-family: sans-serif;
    font-size: 0.9rem;
  }
  #app {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    height: 100vh;
  }
  #toolbar {
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    background-color: #555;
    color: #fff;
    padding: 0.5em;
  }
  #toolbar button,
  #page-mode input {
    color: currentColor;
    background-color: transparent;
    font: inherit;
    border: 1px solid currentColor;
    border-radius: 3px;
    padding: 0.25em 0.5em;
  }
  #toolbar button:hover,
  #toolbar button:focus,
  #page-mode input:hover,
  #page-mode input:focus {
    color: lightGreen;
  }
  #page-mode {
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    padding: 0.25em 0.5em;
  }
  
  #viewport-container {
    flex: 1;
    background: #eee;
    overflow: auto;
  }
  #viewport {
    width: 90%;
    margin: 0 auto;
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    align-items: center;
  }
  #viewport > div {
    text-align: center;
    max-width: 100%;
  }
  #viewport canvas {
    width: 100%;
    box-shadow: 0 2px 5px gray;
  }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>PDF Viewer PDF.js</title>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="./styles.css" />
  </head>

  <body>
    <div id="app">
      <div role="toolbar" id="toolbar">
        <div id="pager">
          <button data-pager="prev">prev</button>
          <button data-pager="next">next</button>
        </div>
        <div id="page-mode">
          <label>Page Mode <input type="number" value="1" min="1"/></label>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div id="viewport-container"><div role="main" id="viewport"></div></div>
    </div>
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/pdfjs-dist@2.0.489/build/pdf.min.js"></script>
    <script>
  (function() {
  let currentPageIndex = 0;
  let pageMode = 1;
  let cursorIndex = Math.floor(currentPageIndex / pageMode);
  let pdfInstance = null;
  let totalPagesCount = 0;

  const viewport = document.querySelector("#viewport");
  window.initPDFViewer = function(pdfURL) {
    pdfjsLib.getDocument(pdfURL).then(pdf => {
      pdfInstance = pdf;
      totalPagesCount = pdf.numPages;
      initPager();
      initPageMode();
      render();
    });
  };

  function onPagerButtonsClick(event) {
    const action = event.target.getAttribute("data-pager");
    if (action === "prev") {
      if (currentPageIndex === 0) {
        return;
      }
      currentPageIndex -= pageMode;
      if (currentPageIndex < 0) {
        currentPageIndex = 0;
      }
      render();
    }
    if (action === "next") {
      if (currentPageIndex === totalPagesCount - 1) {
        return;
      }
      currentPageIndex += pageMode;
      if (currentPageIndex > totalPagesCount - 1) {
        currentPageIndex = totalPagesCount - 1;
      }
      render();
    }
  }
  function initPager() {
    const pager = document.querySelector("#pager");
    pager.addEventListener("click", onPagerButtonsClick);
    return () => {
      pager.removeEventListener("click", onPagerButtonsClick);
    };
  }

  function onPageModeChange(event) {
    pageMode = Number(event.target.value);
    render();
  }
  function initPageMode() {
    const input = document.querySelector("#page-mode input");
    input.setAttribute("max", totalPagesCount);
    input.addEventListener("change", onPageModeChange);
    return () => {
      input.removeEventListener("change", onPageModeChange);
    };
  }

  function render() {
    cursorIndex = Math.floor(currentPageIndex / pageMode);
    const startPageIndex = cursorIndex * pageMode;
    const endPageIndex =
      startPageIndex + pageMode < totalPagesCount
        ? startPageIndex + pageMode - 1
        : totalPagesCount - 1;

    const renderPagesPromises = [];
    for (let i = startPageIndex; i <= endPageIndex; i++) {
      renderPagesPromises.push(pdfInstance.getPage(i + 1));
    }

    Promise.all(renderPagesPromises).then(pages => {
      const pagesHTML = `<div style="width: ${
        pageMode > 1 ? "50%" : "100%"
      }"><canvas></canvas></div>`.repeat(pages.length);
      viewport.innerHTML = pagesHTML;
      pages.forEach(renderPage);
    });
  }

  function renderPage(page) {
    let pdfViewport = page.getViewport(1);

    const container =
      viewport.children[page.pageIndex - cursorIndex * pageMode];
    pdfViewport = page.getViewport(container.offsetWidth / pdfViewport.width);
    const canvas = container.children[0];
    const context = canvas.getContext("2d");
    canvas.height = pdfViewport.height;
    canvas.width = pdfViewport.width;

    page.render({
      canvasContext: context,
      viewport: pdfViewport
    });
  }
})();

      initPDFViewer("https://blog.mozilla.org/security/files/2015/05/HTTPS-FAQ.pdf");
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: yes.it will help for me.but i need open this pdf in android activity page.i have already use plugin to view pdf.just need to open pdf in that activity through url from web server.

Comment: I am no expert in android but opening a webview with a link to the pdf - https://yourdomain.com/viewPdf.html?pdfUrl=your-pdf-url should work right if you have the rendering ready on the viewPdf.html file. Just wanting to understand.

Comment: yes it will open but i don't want give the permission to downloal that file.

Comment: i just need to display that file pdf viewer plugin.

Comment: That's exactly what this plugin will do, once you use this in the html page and create the webpage, when you open the webview with the link to this page, the pdf will render and the user won't get to download it, just view it.

Comment: there is more than 70 pdf in that app to show how it possible.

Comment: where do you store those 70 pdfs? Because its possible for you to pass the id of the pdf and fetch from the database when the webview loads the HTML Page.

Comment: Ok i will get it.Thank you.